# typescript observable .expand usage

Tags: angular, typescript

I get confused by the proper usage of Obervable's .expand() operator within my case. Search doesn't give much samples.

So, i'm trying to run a method / observable recursively and return an observable as the result. Looks a bit messy, advise on how to beautify it is appreciated too :)

Relevant code:

**method:**

```
 private itemsTmp:Item[] = [];
  findRecentItemsAround(radius_current?:number) {
    let radiusKm:number = radius_current? radius_current : 10;
    let radiusLimitKm:number = 50;
    this.itemsTmp = [];


    const result = Observable.create(observer => {
      this._getRecentLocalItems(radiusKm).subscribe((data) => {
        this.itemsTmp = data;
        console.log("Found items:" + this.itemsTmp.length + " radius: "+ radiusKm);
        radiusKm = radiusKm+10;

        if(this.itemsTmp.length < 1 && radiusKm <= radiusLimitKm) {
          return this.findRecentItemsAround(radiusKm);
        }
        else {
          observer.next(this.itemsTmp);
          observer.complete();
        }
      });
    });

    // result.expand(data => {
    //   console.log("In expand");
    // });

    return result;
  }
```

**usage:**

```
this.itemsServiceUtils.findRecentItemsAround().subscribe(data => {
  observer.next(data);
  observer.complete();
});
```

In current state method doesn't run 2nd time. If i uncomment `.expand` - getting an error `result.expand is not a function` Please advice on fix / proper implementation as it seems like i'm misunderstanding something with observables / making some mess :D

Comment: Well, I saw an example where the observable is `Observable().return().expand()` Maybe, `expand` is not at that level object. Maybe you should call another method first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cleaner implementation:

```
 getRecentLocalItems(radiusKm: number) {
     return this._getRecentLocalItems(radiusKm).map(
         t=> { return { distance: radiusKm, results: t } };
     );
 }
 findRecentItemsAround(radiusKm:number, radiusLimitKm:number)  {
     return this.getRecentLocalItems(radiusKm).expand(t=> {
          if (t.distance > radiusLimitKm-radiusKm || t.results.length > 0)
              return Observable.empty();
          return this.getRecentLocalItems(t.distance + 10);
     })
     .filter(t=> t.results.length > 0 || t.distance > radiusLimitKm);
 }
```

Use like this:

```
this.itemsServiceUtils.findRecentItemsAround(10).subscribe(data => {
   //data.distance...
   //data.results...
});
```

Comment: are you sure thats a correct usage of `.expand()`? i'm getting an error `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` on .expand

Comment: did you forget a return statement somewhere?

Comment: no, `this._getRecentLocalItems` returns an observable from `http.get()` which returns a data or empty list. Further you can see here. `.expand()` is imported by `import "rxjs/add/operator/expand";`

Comment: oops... I made a mistake

Comment: The recursive call should be "getRecentLocalItems" not "findRecentItemsAround"

Comment: an error is thrown here `getRecentLocalItems(radiusKm).expand`. Currently i'm commented a recursive call.

Comment: what is the error? you need to import the expand operator: import 'rxjs/add/operator/expand';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165745/discussion-between-user1935987-and-pixelbits).

Comment: Thanks for the simple example! Makes so much more sense now.